# Extended regexp and now regexp.MatchString doesn't exist?

Tags: go

I wanted to extend regexp.Regexp as it doesn't have a quick MatchSuffix or MatchPrefix function. I extended it like so

```
package regexext

type RegexExt struct {
    *regexp.Regexp
    Prefix string
    Suffix string
}
```

With some simple functions

```
func GetRegexExt(expr, prefix, suffix string) *RegexExt {
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(expr)
    return &RegexExt{
        regex,
        prefix,
        suffix,
    }
}

func (f *RegexExt) PrefixMatch(v string) bool {
    if f.Suffix != "" {
        if !strings.HasSuffix(v, f.Suffix) {
            return false
        }
    }
}

func (f *RegexExt) SuffixMatch(v string) bool {
    if f.Prefix != "" {
        if !strings.HasPrefix(v, f.Prefix) {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

but now anywhere else in my code I try and use regexp.MatchString it says it is undefined. Why? Is there a better way to extend the regex struct?

edit:
How I am using regexp.MatchString

```
package somethingelse

import "regexp"

func SimpleMatch(s, v string) {
    ... some parsing ...
    if regexp.MatchString(s, v) {
        // Do something if match
    }
}
```

This is just an example as it is a shared package but even my dependencies say `MatchString not declared by package regexp`

Comment: Show how you are using `regexp.MatchString`.

Comment: What you describe [doesn't happen](https://go.dev/play/p/7w5rnURyewf), provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Kilbo try compiling the code with the `go` tool (e.g., `go build`) rather than with an IDE. If that fixes the problem then that means your IDE is confused (badly configured). If it doesn't fix the issue then that would suggest that you have a custom `regexp` package which is being imported instead of the std lib package, if you believe that not to be the case then you'll need to provide [mcve], or else it'll be difficult to suggest solutions.

Comment: fair enough, unfortunately it's a large package I'm just making an addition to so it'll take some digging to decipher but thanks anyway. If I can reproduce it I'll reopen the question

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my go install was corrupted. Reinstalling Go fixed this issue